# Passar valor de Select html para Controller via Post

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho um formulário onde passo alguns campos via Helper.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ex:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, new { @class = "control-label col-md- 6" })
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class   = " form-control", @placeholder = "Digite um Nome" } })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome)
</div>
```

Até aí tranquilo, porem na minha **VIEW** tenho também um **SELECT**:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    @Html.Label("Pais", new { @class = "col-md-3" })
    <select id="cmbPais" class="form-control">
    <option>Carregar Paises</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    @Html.Label("Estado", new { @class = "col-md-3" })
    <select id="cmbEstado" class="form-control">
    <option>Carregar Estados</option>
    </select>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
     @Html.Label("Cidade", new { @class = "col-md-3" })
      <select id="cmbCidade" class="form-control">
      <option>Carregar Cidades</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

onde preciso passar o valor selecionado para o controller para efetuar o cadastro do usuário. Como posso fazer isso  ?

Comment: Qual o nome do campo `Estado` no seu `@model`? É `cmbEstado` mesmo?

Comment: Editei a pergunta. o que quero passar para a **Controller** é um valor CidadeId. Que obtenho via Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está carregando a lista de cidades?

Se a CidadeId existe no seu Model, você pode substituir o atributo `select` pelo HtmlHelper [`DropDownFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx), assim:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CidadeId, <sua lista>, "Carregar Cidades")
```

O Razor irá com isso criar um atributo `select` com todas as `options` passadas na lista do segundo parametro, além de fazer bind para a propriedade do seu model.

Explicando os parâmetros:

- O primeiro parâmetro irá armazenar o valor que for selecionado na
  lista.
- O segundo parâmetro será a sua lista. Note que ela é do tipo
  `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` então se você carrega ela no
  `Controller`, ele precisa ser este tipo. Caso você carregue via
  jQuery (apenas incluindo options no atributo `select`), não se preocupe
  com essa propriedade e apenas passe `new List<SelectListItem>()`.
- Já o terceiro parâmetro é o valor para apresentar caso nenhum item
  esteja selecionado.

Caso você não tenha a CidadeId no seu model, utilize o HtmlHelper [`DropDownList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist(v=vs.118).aspx) no lugar, desta forma:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("CidadeId",  <sua lista>, "Carregar Cidades")
```

Assim, basta criar um parâmetro chamado `CidadeId` no `POST` do seu `Controller` e ele irá passar o valor selecionado para este parâmetro

Answer (score 2):

Se você quer passar `CidadeId` para o *Controller*, usar o nome apropriado de variável já faz isso por você:

```
<select id="CidadeId" class="form-control">
    <option>Carregar Cidades</option>
</select>
```

Ou você pode usar Razor:

```
@Html.DropDown("CidadeId", /* Coloque aqui a lista que populará a DropDown */)
```